# Music Tracker Software allowing Keyboard Input for Playing Piano

Tags: software-recommendation, keyboard, music

I'm looking for a piece of software that is a tracking studio, that allows you to use your keyboard to perform at least piano parts, or at best, any instrument.

Needless to say I mean keyboard as in my QWERTY keyboard I'm typing into right now. MIDI support is optional, but probably already there on any piece of software like this.

I've used [LMMS](http://lmms.sourceforge.net/) in the past, which (aside from the hard coded AZERTY input method) was a wonderfully simple program that offered plenty of high-end VSTs and features to grow into.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have this in GarageBand. Keyboard mapping.

[image]

If you decide, one day, to link a midi keayboard, the only thing you need is the Midi to USB cable. Nothing else.

Comment: Oh snap, how could I have forgotten that garageband DOES have this feature? Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 0):

Give [Renoise](http://www.renoise.com/) a try — it's keyboard-centric, and supports VST and AU.